# Far Manager pane is only showing folders, not files -- how do I change this back?

Tags: far-manager

I am a big fan of Far Manager. I'm currently using version 3.0.6161.0 x64. But I've got myself into a state I can't get out of, although I'm sure it's there in the built-in help if I could only find it.

The problem is, the left-hand pane is only showing folders, not files. I usually set  the view mode indicator (yellow, top left) to `x`, to order files by extension. But now it is showing `x*`, and is only showing folders, not files. How do I get it to show files as well? I'm tearing my hair out over this.

Here is the complete list of my non-default settings (obtained by `far:config` and `Ctrl-H`):

```
Confirmations.Delete          │boolean│false
Editor.ExternalEditorName     │string │notepad++ !.!      
Editor.UseExternalEditor      │boolean│true         
Layout.LeftHeightDecrement    │integer│10 = 0xA     
Layout.RightHeightDecrement   │integer│10 = 0xA     
Panel.Left.SortMode           │integer│2 = 0x2      
Panel.Right.SortMode          │integer│2 = 0x2      
Panel.SortFolderExt           │boolean│true         
Screen.Clock                  │boolean│false        
System.AutoSaveSetup          │boolean│true
```

Comment: To return to the initial state, you could uninstall Far Manager, clean up leftovers in its folders and reinstall.

Comment: Yes, @harrymc, but surely there's just a button I have to press, if I only knew which one?

Answer (score 3):

`Commands -> File filter panel (Ctrl+I)` and remove all filters (with X key).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem without re-installing Far Manager, by deleting the file `C:\Users\Tony\AppData\Roaming\Far Manager\Profile\filters.db`. But it seems like a dreadful hack, and I would still be grateful if anybody could tell me the right way to do this!

Comment: So you deleted the Far Manager profile. That seems like a acceptable solution to a profile that was clearly corrupt.

Comment: @Ramhound: No, I only deleted `filters.db`, a small part of the profile. I managed to keep all my important settings (folder shortcuts, environment variables, commands etc).

Comment: Yes, but the behavior you describe, was at least to me a filtering issue. Suspect if you replaced “x*” with “*” you would find neither files or folder’s would be displayed.